# Wordcloud with a specific shape

Tags: r, text-mining, word-cloud

Suppose, I have a dataframe which contains some words with their frequencies. I want to create a wordcloud in R with the words inside the shape of a logo, for example, the twitter logo just like this:
[image]

For the wordcloud, there is a package named `wordcloud2` and running the demo only gives a square image of the words. How would I add a specific image of my choice to be the shape of the wordcloud?

`wordcloud2(demoFreq)` only ouputs a square.

Comment: Ok sorry. typing into google was giving only python solution.

Comment: I don't think this question is "asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `wordcloud2` package for that. It allows you to use any image as the mask. Just put in the working directory and link to it using `figpath`. Below is the code I used to make the wordcloud. Below that is the wordcloud. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2jeo.jpg) is the image I used as the mask.

```
library(wordcloud2)
wordcloud2(demoFreq, figPath = "twitter.jpg")
```

[image]

Comment: can we use it with `Quanteda's` DFM?