# Create a wordcloud contained in a specific image

Tags: r

I just tried to create a wordcloud contained in [Africa continent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5Jhc.png) using `wordcloud2` but I couldn't see the words in the image.

```
library(wordcloud2)

cloud <- data.frame(
  word = c(
  "Atlantic",
  "Coho",
  "Rainbow",
  "Arctic",
  "Chinook",
  "Danube",
  "Grayling"
),
freq = c(
  6,
  7,
  9,
  10,
  3,
  9,
  2
))
wordcloud2(data = cloud,
       figPath = "africa3.png"
       )
```

## UPDATE

I somehow figured it out but the words are not fitting well in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvr3H.png). Someone can improve the following code:

```
myFun <- function(n = 5000) {
      a <- do.call(paste0, replicate(5, sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE), FALSE))
      paste0(a, sprintf("%04d", sample(9999, n, TRUE)), sample(LETTERS, n, TRUE))
    }

    cloud <- data.frame(
      word =  myFun(100),
      freq = sample(30, size = 100, replace = TRUE))

    wordcloud2(data = cloud, figPath = "africa4.png",color = "skyblue",shuffle = F, size = 0.5, ellipticity = 1.5)
```

Comment: First you don't need the last comma in `wordcloud2`. Second, I think there is a bug in using letters and images as a background. I've never heard back regarding issues with `lettercloud`. I could be wrong about this though.

Comment: Here is a reference to an issue that is still open: https://github.com/Lchiffon/wordcloud2/issues/12

Comment: @NelsonGon thanks but someone made it to work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028462/wordcloud-with-a-specific-shape. It seems my problem is to get the right kind of image format. I tried to make the image transparent and it didn't work.

Comment: Well, I've tested with several formats and it doesn't work. Update it it does.

Comment: It works but you need to find the right number of words and wordcloud2 parameters.  Check this out. I added more code in the original request so that others can improve it.