# How to make a wordcloud in R using a custom shape with wordcloud2?

Tags: r, wordcloud2

I want to create a wordcloud in R where the words are within the shape of a picture. A common example is to use the Twitter bird shape, as shown in [Wordcloud with a specific shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028462/wordcloud-with-a-specific-shape).

Although I followed multiple tutorials, my code always results in an empty sheet. The standard visualization without the shape works fine.

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(RColorBrewer)

wordcloud2(demoFreq, size = 0.7, shape = 'star') # -> this works fine

#put picture in current working directory
getwd() #get current working directory
wordcloud2(demoFreq, figPath="heart.png", size = 1.5, color = "skyblue", backgroundColor="black") # -> this does not show anything
```

Answer (score 2):

[Heart image link i used](http://www.supercoloring.com/sites/default/files/styles/drawing_full/public/fif/2017/11/black-heart-template-paper-craft.png). I installed the `worldcloud2` from github master repo as I was troubleshooting, not sure if that helped or not. Nothing rendered for me until I added `size=1` in the worldcloud2 function. I also saved the picture as *.jpg*

```
library(wordcloud2)
library(RColorBrewer)
#library(devtools)
#install_github("lchiffon/wordcloud2")


wordcloud2(demoFreq,size = 1,figPath = "heart.jpg")
```

[image]